# How to format a date time string of format "3/22/2018 12:24:29 PM" into sql timestamp to insert into h2 in memory database?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, timestamp, h2, scalatest

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.sql.Timestamp
object SetSuite {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val date = "3/22/2018 12:24:29 PM"

    var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a" );
    println(formatter.parse(date)
  }
}
```

How do I format the above string into a sql timestamp? Is there any library which can parse into the necessary format?

Comment: For testing you can benefit from reading about [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/) that would help to setup fully isolated persistence JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your pattern actually:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
object SetSuite {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val date = "03/22/2018 12:24:29 PM" //Note-Here

    var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a" )
    println(formatter.parse(date))
  }
}
```

In the above example, you were expecting the pattern to be MM, but you were passing M in the datetimeformatter.

To correct you example:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
object SetSuite {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val date = "3/22/2018 12:24:29 PM"

    var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a" ) //Note-Here
    println(formatter.parse(date))
  }
}
```

Using the above formatter will fix it.

Comment: I tried the format you have suggested and still I am facing the issue. Here is the exception : java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '3/22/2018 12:24:29 PM' could not be parsed, unparsed text found

Comment: @ChandrakanthK, did you run the same program above discussed?